# On the logarithmic derivative of an analytic function

Tags: cv.complex-variables

I have reached upto this situation while exploring some properties of analytic functions which are bounded on the unit circle.
Suppose  $f(z)$ be such an analytic  function in the closed unit disc with $f(z)\neq 0$ in $|z|\leq 1$ and $|f(z)|$ attains its maximum at $z_0=e^{i\theta_0}$ on the unit circle $|z|=1. $   $f(z)$ also satisfies the conditions that 
$$e^{i\theta_0}\frac{f'(e^{i\theta_0})}{f(e^{i\theta_0})}\geq 0$$
and $$\Re \left\{ e^{i\theta}\frac{f'(e^{i\theta})}{f(e^{i\theta})}\right\}\leq M,$$ for any real $\theta$ and for some fixed $M>0.$  I have been  trying   relating $|f'(e^{i\theta})|$ with $|f(e^{i\theta_0})|$  with inequality.  Would I get an inequality of type $|f'(e^{i\theta})|\leq M|f(e^{i\theta_0})|$ under any circumstances? Suggestions will  help me in going ahead.

Would it be easier to proceed if I take $ f(z)$ a polynomial?

Comment: What does your first condition mean? The left hand side is a complex number right?

Comment: @user159888 Yes, for some examples it will be a real number, but for most example it will not be right?

Comment: Could you explain the role of the first condition? Is the  conclusione false, without?

Comment: @user250938 let $|f(z)|=R$; then the maximum condition for $R$ at some $|w|=r$ on $|z|=r$ implies $\partial R /(\partial r) (w)=0$ which translates into $wf'(w)/f(w)$ real by taking $\log f=\log R+i \arg f$ near $w$; the above is obviously true for non-zero minima or local maxima too, but now using specifically the global maximum property on the circle we get that $wf'(w)/f(w) \ge 0$ by a little proof involving Schwarz lemma

Comment: Great approach. That is right.

Comment: @user159888 I see, the first condition is always satisfied. By the way, once the quantity is real I see it is nonegative since it is a maximum (the modulus must be non decreasing in the radial direction), without using the Schwartz Lemma.

Comment: The function  $f(z)=\exp\left ({\frac{1}{z} \log (1-z)}\right )$ is bounded in D and $zf'/f=\log (1-z)+i \arg (1-z)$.  Its real part is upper bounded (but not lower bounded), the imaginary part is bounded. However $f'$ is unbounded and the estimate fails. This seems to be a counterexample. If it works, an approximation argument should show that any estimate as above fails on functions holomorphic up to the boundary.